# tshark can't open /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Installed wireshark and tshark, neither can open /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon/ files.  /sys/kernel/debug/usbmon file not there.  Can't add a new folder as root. Have followed wireshark instructions regarding running on Ubuntu 18.04, failed to solve.  How can I add the appropriate directories/files to /sys/kernel/debug so I can monitor USB device?  Any suggestions?  Other monitoring software that doesn't need access to /sys/kernel/debug?

Answer (score 0):

Found good solution at: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/usbmon.html,
where use of usbmon gets logs via cat to log file.  Rough, but have track of usb traffic desired.